# Symfony form collections for dynamic add entity relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I create form for invoice and want create add form for add customer, read cook book and have erro

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at new:32
```

why `$('<a href="#" class="add_customer_link">Add a customer</a>')` return error ?

this template

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.companyReference) }}
{{ form_row(form.customerReference) }}

<h3>Customer</h3>
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.customer.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for customer in form.customer %}
       <li>{{ form_row(customer.name) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   <a href="#" class="add_customer_link">Add a tag</a>
</ul>

{{ form_end(form) }}



<script>
    var $collectionHolder;
    var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_customer_link">Add a customer</a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

        $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I'am doing wrong and how to doing right ?

Comment: Do you include `jquery` plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<script>
var $collectionHolder;
var $addTagLink;
var $newLinkLi;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_customer_link">Add a customer</a>');
    $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
    $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
});
```